# How do I resolve "result:19 constraint violation error" for changing manager attribute using ldap3?

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap3

I'm trying to change to Microsoft Active Directory user details from Linux using LDAP3 by python.

I could be able to change the user's info such as mobile,department and company,etc successfully but I'm getting an error for just manager attribute.
An exact error is

```
{'result':19,'description':'constraintViolation','dn':'','message':'000020B5:
AttrErr: DSID-03152804, #1:\n\t0: 00020B%:....}
```

```
from ldap3 import Connection,Server,ALL, MODIFY_REPLACE
s =Server('host',get_info=ALL)
c = Connection(s,user='****',password='****')
c.bind()

c.modify('CN=*,OU=*,OU=*,OU=*,OU=*, DC=*,DC=*,DC=*',{'manager':[(MODIFY_REPLACE,['managerID'])]})

print (c.result)


c.modify('CN=*,OU=*,OU=*,OU=*,OU=*, DC=*,DC=*,DC=*',{'Department':[(MODIFY_REPLACE,['Team'])]})

print (c.result)
```

Comment: workaround MODIFY_DELETE followed with MODIFY_ADD